# Copy a sheet from another open workbook into current workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that takes `Sheet1` from another, already open, workbook and copy it into a the workbook that will use the data. The macro will be run from the workbook that will be receiving the copied sheet and the file I want the data from will always be named the same.

I've tried the follow code, but it either just copies incorrectly or doesn't work.

```
Workbooks("FileIWantToCopyFrom.XLSX").Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
```

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FileIWantToCopyFrom.XLSX").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Workbooks("FileIWantToCopyFrom.XLSX").Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`.

Comment: Additional point:  Make sure the sheet name isn't already in the target workbook.

Comment: I think you deleted the other comment, but this code works! What was happening is it was copying it into the main macro excel file and not into the new workbook I was actually running it in. Should it be doing that?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing the code... so you'd have to specify the new workbook instead.

Comment: how would you go about doing that? As far as I understand I need an Excel document open that is macro enabled and has the macro on it in order to run the macro. is there something else I should be doing that would be more efficient?

Comment: "the workbook that will be receiving the copied sheet" - are you opening it programmatically, or is it a new workbook? In any case, instead of `ThisWorkbook`, you need a reference to the workbook that will be receiving the sheet.

Comment: I figured out if I use ```ActiveWorkbook``` instead of ```ThisWorkbook``` it does what I am wanting it to do. Thanks for your help!